# I get an error, if i want to publish my app to the apple store

Tags: ios, app-store

i get this error:

Note that the Bundle ID cannot be changed if the first version of your app has been approved or if you have enabled Game Center or the iAd Network.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change the Bundle ID once the app is already approved. Meaning if you are trying to submit an update to an app that's Bundle ID is foo.foo.com you can not submit the new update with a different Bundle ID (ex:foo2.foo.com). They must be identical in order to establish that it is the same application.  Bundle ID's are also case sensitive so make sure they match 100%.